# ms access machine data source Settings

Tags: ms-access-2007

I have a question regarding selecting machine data source in ms access 2010/2007. When I run query, need to select machine data source all the time. So is there any way or setting which takes by default that server for all queries that we run on that computer?

Current steps:

Click on Run query (!) icon
Select machine data source
click on machine data source. 
Run query.

I want to change these steps by eliminating step 2 & 3. Kindly guide me on this.

Comment: Just to clarify: These are pass-through queries in Access that use an ODBC Machine Data Source pointing to a remote database, correct?

Comment: Yes that is correct.

Comment: Can anyone please comment on my confusion?

Answer (score 3):

If you create a pass-through query in Access and do not supply a DSN (or connection string) in the "ODBC Connect Str" (`.Connect`) property then you will be prompted for a Data Source each time.

[image: noDSN.png]

To avoid that prompt, add the DSN name (or connection string values) to the property and save the pass-through query:

[image: withDSN.png]

Comment: Thank you for your response. Could you please paste snap again? It is not visible.

Comment: @Sharmil I can see the screenshots okay. Try reloading the page.